# Why is this question said to be seeking recommendations?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-question, reopen-closed, recommendation-questions

This questions was closed because someone said it is seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more.

[Cosmos DB: What is document link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67931533/cosmos-db-what-is-document-link)

It’s just asking the definition. What recommendations did he or she think it’s seeking?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've no idea.

Probably using the word *document* in your question triggers all kind of close votes based on the fact that the previous 99 questions the close voters saw were asking for a link to a document. Your question asks the same at first glance but on second reading it is clear it asks how to use the readDocument API that takes  a *link* as parameter ...

I've made a minimal clarifying edit and cast a re-open vote.